# SharePoint 2013 - Excel Web Access - Can't Contact the server

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel-services, alternate-access-mapping

I have a BI site configured with Excel and Reporting services and all the other required services. I have extended this site and all is fine when I use farm account accessing the site through Internet.

When I use a account with a SharePoint Group 'Read' permission, I can use PowerView for SharePoint reports and SSRS report (a parametrised report deployed to document library) but I get following error for Excel PivotChart report:

'Can't Contact the Server. 
We're not able able to contact the server. It might not be responding, 
or your internet connection may have been interrupted. Please try again.'

The Excel PivotChart report renders fine but is not able to refresh data when slicers applied hence the error.

I have spend a lot of time to resolve the error but I am unable to find out why if a SSRS report can refresh data, a Excel PivotChart can not using the same account. I can not find relevant message in ULS and Event Viewer just registers:

'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.UsageProcessingTimerJob 
threw an exception. More information is included below.
Call to Excel Services returned an error.'

Please help me to resolve the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting PowerPivot can be complex.  How is your workbook configured for authentication?  Are you sure the workbook is utilizing the unattend account?  I recommend you do two things:

1. Increase ULS logging to verbose for Excel Services.
2. When refreshing data - run SQL Profiler on your SSAS PowerPivot instance and see what the traffic looks like.  This one alone will tell you a lot right away, as you can see if request is even hitting the instance or specifically what account is being denied.

I've found with PowerPivot, alot of the time it is  either Permissions or a missing connection provider.

Comment: Hello @jshelbyjr and all, it was a silly mistake by me. The other account didn't have permission in SSAS PowerPivot instance. All is nice now. Thanks